# Specifying relationships with YAML for Doctrine

Tags: doctrine, yaml

Just trying to specify some tables structures and models for Doctrine in a YAML file. I'm going through the documentation on this page: http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/1.2/docs/manual/yaml-schema-files/en

I haven't quite got a grasp on what each line in the **relations** section is doing.

Here's some sample YAML from that page:

```
User:
    columns:
    username:
      type: string(255)
    password:
      type: string(255)
    contact_id:
      type: integer
  relations:
    Contact:
      class: Contact
      local: contact_id
      foreign: id
      foreignAlias: User
      foreignType: one
      type: one
```

Specifically, **relations**, in order:

**Contact** is.. I am guessing the name of the other corresponding table pertaining to this relationship?

**class: contact** is.. what exactly? The name of the model that will be created from this YAML?

**local: contact_id** is the local key, I understand this.

**foreign: id** is the field name of the foreign key, I understand this

**foreignAlias: User** what is this line doing?

**foreignType: one**
**type: one:** I am guessing these two lines together specify the type of relationship, eg, one-to-one?

Thanks for any and all help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Contact is.. I am guessing the name of the other corresponding table pertaining to this >relationship?

Nope. It is the Name of the object you later use when accessing contact information of a user.

$user->Contact->email

This can be different from the Class-Name

> class: contact is.. what exactly? The name of the model that will be created from this >YAML?

That is the class you are referencing. Needs to be the Classname in the YAML (i.e. Contact)

> local: contact_id is the local key, I understand this.
> foreign: id is the field name of the foreign key, I understand this
>
> foreignAlias: User what is this line doing?

This is the name you can access the user information from a contact object.

$contact->User->username

> foreignType: one
> type: one: I am guessing these two lines together specify the type of relationship, eg, >one-to-one?
> Jepp, you are right here.

Comment: I need to use 14 characters to say Thank you.